# Escape character in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I stuck in escape sequence in program.

I am getting input from xml file in single quotes.

So in string it may contain any escape sequence.

So what I want to do is consider next character after escape character as normal character.

```
Example: '\abc\\t'
 Output: 'abc\t'
```

So for that I created regular expression which is:

```
Regex.Replace(SearchString, @"\\?(?<Character>)", "${Character}");
```

But it replaces all escape character and gives output :

```
abct
```

Please help me how can I do it?

Comment: Why not make it a literal / verbatim string, then work with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The named group in your regular expression matches nothing, so it does the same as `Replace(@"\", "")`.

Match one character in the group:

```
SearchString = Regex.Replace(SearchString, @"\\(.)", "$1");
```

Comment: Thanks. it works great can you tell me how can i understand and create regular expression? I found regular expression very tricky to build and unable to understand all parts. Can you also tell me the mistakes that i done in my expression?

Comment: It will also convert escaped tab to 't'. Example @"\t\tint i;\r\n" will convert to to @"ttint i;rn". @LOL Is that what are you looking for?

Comment: @LOL: Learning to write regular expressons is a long journey, and learing to read them is even longer... It's no surprise that you find it very tricky, as it is. You should be able to find some tutorials to take you through the basics, then you can look at the documenation to get the complete picture. Regarding your expression, there are two problems. You have made the backslash optional, which means that it will also match things that doesn't start with a backslash, and you have made a group that just has a name but doesn't match anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Regex.Replace(SearchString, @"\\(?<Character>[^\\])", "${Character}");
```

Comment: That works, but it replaces every character in the string with itself instead of just the escaped characters.

Comment: Yes, I realized the mistake. Edited my post now.

Comment: You shouldn't use `[^\\]` to match the character, that keeps it from matching \\, so it will match \t in \\t instead of \\. Try the string `\abc\\\\t` for example, where the result is `abc\\\t` rather than `abc\\t`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need parse your string character by character. Pseudo-code:

```
Loop through all characters c:
    If c is escape character:
        Read next character and do something special (\t is tab, \\ is backslash, ...)
    Else:
        Copy character to output
```

Comment: Yes, normally you would do that, but in this case the OP doesn't want the escaped characters to have a special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do like:

```
SearchString = SearchString.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

It would give:

```
\abc\t
```

Here escaped `\t` is now treated as a "tab character".

It is what you are looking for ?